# configure: error: No working boost sleep implementation found

Tags: compiling

On Ubuntu 18.04 using the `/depends` for `./configure` but I keep getting this error:

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.47.0 (104700) includes in "/home/tony/crypto/bitcoin/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/share/../include"... yes
checking for boostlib >= 1.47.0 (104700) lib path in "/home/tony/crypto/bitcoin/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/share/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"... no
checking for boostlib >= 1.47.0 (104700) lib path in "/home/tony/crypto/bitcoin/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/share/../lib64"... no
checking for boostlib >= 1.47.0 (104700) lib path in "/home/tony/crypto/bitcoin/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/share/../libx32"... no
checking for boostlib >= 1.47.0 (104700) lib path in "/home/tony/crypto/bitcoin/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/share/../lib"... yes
checking for boostlib >= 1.47.0 (104700)... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_system-mt-x64... yes
checking whether the Boost::Filesystem library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_filesystem-mt-x64... yes
checking whether the Boost::Thread library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_thread-mt-x64... yes
checking whether the Boost::Chrono library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_chrono-mt-x64... yes
checking whether the Boost::Unit_Test_Framework library is available... yes
checking for dynamic linked boost test... no
checking for mismatched boost c++11 scoped enums... ok
configure: error: No working boost sleep implementation found.
```

The command called is

```
./configure --prefix=`pwd`/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --disable-wallet
```

. I've tried this without the depends and with. Tried to checkout to `0.18.1` and on master, but getting same error. Help very much appreciated.

---

Extra info from `config.log`

```
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.15.0-65-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 17 17:06:04 UTC 2019
```

More from `config.log` here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/v6nhPvW68s/

Comment: Seems like the depends build wasn't completed. Try rebuilding the dependencies and see if there are any errors there.

Comment: @AndrewChow Running `make` in `/depends` gives me
`copying packages: boost openssl libevent qrencode zlib qt expat libxcb xcb_proto libXau xproto freetype fontconfig bdb miniupnpc zeromq
to: /home/tony/crypto/bitcoin/depends/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`

Doesn't seem to give any errors when building depends.

Comment: Tried rebuilding twice by deleting /depends, doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem. Had these lines in my `.bashrc` and commenting them out fixed it:

```
alias gcc="gcc-8"
alias g++="g++-8"
export CC="gcc"
export CXX="/usr/bin/gcc-8"
export PATH=/usr/local/clang_8.0.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/clang_8.0.0/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Why this caused `./configure` to error out, I have no idea. But problem solved.